# Guidelines on how to use Cucumber Java Scenario interface

Tags: java, cucumber

I'm looking for information/guidelines on how to use `io.cucumber.core.api.Scenario` interface?
I read through the [API reference documentation](https://javadoc.io/static/io.cucumber/cucumber-core/4.7.2/index.html?io/cucumber/core/api/Scenario.html) and [Official Cucumber-Java documentation](https://cucumber.io/docs/cucumber/reporting/) and some scattered usage examples, but still couldn't figure out what is the correct way to use it, and what happens when I call methods of this interface.

Why would I like to find this info? I am maintaining a sizable automation framework, and moving it to use dependency injection for step classes. But the previous developer used `scenario.write` as a logging tool and I was not sure how to refactor that, or what implementation to bind to `Scenario` interface.

---

**Upd**. Here is an example of what I have in classes that that use `Scenario.write` as logger.

```
// Let's assume that code below resides in some Java class that defines Gherkin steps
private Scenario scenario;

@Before()
public void before(Scenario scenario) {
    this.scenario = scenario;
}

@Then("^Received XML file should match \"([^\"]*)\"$")
public void receivedXmlFileShouldMath(String expectedFilePath) {

    // ignoring how we read expected file and where received file content is stored

    scenario.write("Ignoring date field in xml message");
    compareXml(expectedXml, actualXml)
}
```

If it is possible I would like to move Scenario injection to the class constructor, or use some other technique to still get the message in the report.

Answer (score 2):

In my experience, that interface is used in one of two ways:

1. getting info on the test case (getting the name, id, status of the test case, etc)
2. writing to the report file (screenshots and text)

Some example usages for No. 1:

```
@Before
public void setUp(Scenario scenario) {
    System.out.println(scenario.getName() + " is starting.")
}

@After
public void afterTest(Scenario scenario) {
    if (scenario.isFailed()) {
        // do stuff
    }
}
```

Typical example for No 2 is taking screenshot on failure:

```
@After
public void embedScreenshot(Scenario scenario) {
  if (scenario.isFailed()) {
    try {
      byte[] screenshot = ((TakesScreenshot) driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.BYTES);
      scenario.embed(screenshot, "image/png");
      scenario.write("This text is written to the report...")
    } catch (Exception e) {
      // do stuff
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: thank you for your response. I've seen the examples like ones you showed. Would you mind checking the update I added to my question.

Comment: Sorry, don't know how to do that.

Comment: @Mate_Mrse, I will go to Cucumber Devs and if they provide me with a decent answer post it here.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make use of scenario interface in every  step definition , then set the scenario into a context and then get it.

```
public class Context {
//use lombok 
@Getter @Setter
private Scenario scenario;
} 

public class Hook
{

@Before
public void setUp(Scenario scenario)
{
  context.setScenrario(scenario)
}
```